# Unable to connect to an Oracle XE database from another PC, or a local program / webpage

Tags: windows, fedora, oracle-11g

I've installed an Oracle 11g XE on a Linux Fedora machine, successfully created a user, and imported a database into it.

My ultimate goal here is to connect an existing PHP website (also residing on the machine) via OCI8 and MDB2, but I'm having problems doing that (despite the local trial noted below) - so, I'm taking things one small step at a time.

I wanted to test the connection, see if there are any problems there, before moving on to more complex solutions.

- Using the Linux machine itself, I tried logging on to the Oracle database via `SQLPLUS` in the command line. This works fine.
- Using a Windows-based PC, via Oracle SQL developer, however, returned the following error:

  > Status: Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The network adapter could not
  >   establish the connection.

  Which doesn't tell me much. I can ping the Linux machine from Windows, but using   telnet and specifying the port (1521) returns the following error:

  > Could not open connection to host, on port 1521: Connection failed.

So I'm assuming something is wrong with my Oracle Setup.

What else could I check or do to resolve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Additional details:

Here's what I'm using to connect to the Linux machine:

[image]

Pretty standard stuff (default port: 1521, SID: xe) so far.

I also recently installed SQL Developer on said Linux server, and tried connecting. Connection successful, no issues so far.

Comment: Any firewalls on your Oracle server?

Comment: I typed in `service iptables stop` just to be sure, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lsnrctl start`?

Comment: TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER already started

Answer (score 1):

When you use sqlplus from the host machine, sqlplus uses IPC communication. When you try to connect to the Oracle instance remotely, you will use tnslistener. IS your listener running?

```
lsnrctl status
```

If yes, then maybe it's your firewall. Turn off the built-in firewall and try again

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

Comment: Yes, lsnrctl is running (instance XE, status READY, has 1 handlers for this device). As for the firewall, that latter command returns `No such file or directory`.

Comment: maybe it's 'service iptables stop' run by root

Comment: I stopped the service (thanks for that command), but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the SID is xe? Is the SID xe enlisted when you issue the command lsnrctl status <LISTENERNAME>?

Comment: It's service, actually. Default service. Service XE has 1 instance, status ready. To tell you the truth, I'm not too well versed in Oracle stuff.

Comment: You might try this: . oraenv -> xe, sqlplus / as sysdba, alter system register

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the `oraenv -> xe` part. Do I just type that whole thing in? The rest I recognize as a log-in attempt, plus an alteration of something.

Comment: You need to source the script like '. oraenv', and you need to input the SID (which is 'xe')of your database to that script. It sets environment variables and puts sqlplus on PATH too.

Comment: I put in `. oranev` which then proceeded to ask me about ORACLE_SID = [XE] ?. I put in XE for the latter, but all I got the following: "ORACLE_BASE environment is not available for the current user ID root. You can set ORACLE_BASE manually if it is required." I did try installing an SQL Developer on the Linux machine, but that also connected just fine.

Comment: You just source the script oraenv which sets env. variables: ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID mainly

Comment: How do I source the script? I'm very, very sorry about this - I'm not too good with Linux-based PCs.